# How do I convert HashiCorp Configuration Language into JSON?

Tags: go, terraform

In order to better understand terraform I'd like to be able to translate HCL into the equivalent JSON.  I got the HCL parser (https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl) to build and the tests to run but I don't see any command to take in an HCL file and output JSON.

There's a python implementation of HCL and it includes a utility that converts HCL to JSON, but it has some rather strange/unexpected behavior, and I would like to confirm that the behavior comes from the HCL language and isn't specific to the python implementation.  e.g.

```
> cat foo.tf 
service {
    key = "aaa"
}

service {
    key = 0x10
    foo = "bar"
}

> hcltool foo.tf 
{
    "service": [
        {
            "foo": "bar",
            "key": "aaa"
        },
        {
            "key": 16
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: are you sure your tf is correct HCL? I'm not familiar enough with the language specs of hcl, but the aws provider that I'm familiar with uses two words before the `{` like `type "identifier" {`, for example `variable "ami" {`

Comment: I would just unmarshal from HCL to a Go struct, then marshal that Go struct to JSON.

Comment: HCL doesn't have a defined spec, and there is no direct translation from HCL to JSON. To further complicate matters, Terraform requires the AST structure of the HCL to represent different types, so there are some nested constructs that can't be described in JSON at all. Because of these ambiguities, there isn't a tool to that can take arbitrary HCL and convert it to valid JSON. See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9354.

Answer (score 12):

There is an open source project `json2hcl` and you can use for help, but terraform hcl is not standard as they designed. Explain here:

https://github.com/kvz/json2hcl/issues/4#issuecomment-275513256

> Sadly, this behavior is caused by Hasicorp's official HCL library due to ambiguities in the HCL format. Therefore, we are not really able to improve this situation. We had similar discussions in the past, if you may want to read more on this topic and why this will probably not be changed in the future:

Related repo that you can install the tool:

https://github.com/kvz/json2hcl

Here's an example fixtures/infra.tf.json being converted to HCL:

```
$ json2hcl < fixtures/infra.tf.json > fixtures/infra.tf
```

As a bonus, the other way around is also supported via the -reverse flag:

```
$ json2hcl -reverse < fixtures/infra.tf
```

Comment: The question was to convert HCL to JSON, not JSON to HCL.

Comment: If you read it carefully, my answer already mentioned, json2hcl gives 2-way convert.

Answer (score 5):

This site is useful for one-off conversions between HCL, JSON, and YAML:
https://www.hcl2json.com/

Comment: When converting to YAML comments are dropped as there is an intermediate conversion to JSON. What a pity.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [HCL2](https://pypi.org/project/python-hcl2/), like below:

```
with open('main.tf', 'r') as file:
    temp_dict = hcl2.load(file)
```